# module 'apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients.bigquery' has no attribute 'TableFieldSchema'?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to parse schema from a json file,which contains schema file of a bigquery table.
I am using following code.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import parse_table_schema_from_json
import json

schema_data = json.dumps(json.load(open("/content/sample_data/schema.json")))
table_schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(schema_data)
print(table_schema)
```

But it throws ,following error.

```
module 'apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients.bigquery' has no attribute 'TableFieldSchema'
```

I have installed gcp specific apache beam library using
pip install apache-beam[gcp].

Can anyone help or know how to resolve it?

My schema:

Its contains nested and repeated columns.

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "fields": [
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "second",
          "type": "INTEGER"
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "minute",
          "type": "INTEGER"
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "hour",
          "type": "INTEGER"
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "timeZoneId",
          "type": "STRING"
        },
        {
          "fields": [
            {
              "mode": "NULLABLE",
              "name": "month",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "mode": "NULLABLE",
              "name": "day",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "mode": "NULLABLE",
              "name": "year",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            }
          ],
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "date",
          "type": "RECORD"
        }
      ],
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "lastModifiedDateTime",
      "type": "RECORD"
    },
    {
      "mode": "REPEATED",
      "name": "companionCreativeIds",
      "type": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "masterCreativeId",
      "type": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "name",
      "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "id",
      "type": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "fields": [
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "name",
          "type": "STRING"
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "value",
          "type": "STRING"
        }
      ],
      "mode": "REPEATED",
      "name": "soft_error_fields",
      "type": "RECORD"
    },
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "dw_ingest_time",
      "type": "TIMESTAMP"
    },
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "dw_partition_date",
      "type": "DATE"
    },
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "dw_publish_time",
      "type": "TIMESTAMP"
    },
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "dw_source_object_name",
      "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "dw_batch_id",
      "type": "STRING"
    }
  ]
}
```

###########IGNORE######
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
############################

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the following Json schema :

`schema.json` file

```json
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "r",
      "type": "RECORD",
      "mode": "REQUIRED",
      "description": "r description",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "s",
          "type": "STRING",
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "description": "s description"
        },
        {
          "name": "n",
          "type": "INTEGER",
          "mode": "REQUIRED",
          "description": "n description"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I checked the format from this [class](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools_test.py)

I used an unit test and it worked correctly as expected :

```py
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import parse_table_schema_from_json
from apache_beam.testing.test_pipeline import TestPipeline

  def test_pipeline(self):
      with TestPipeline() as p:
          schema_file = f'{ROOT_DIR}/tests/schema.json'

          schema_data = json.dumps(json.load(open(schema_file)))
          table_schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(schema_data)
```

2 things to help you :

- I used a different import for `parse_table_schema_from_json` method because the other is now deprecated
- I firstly tested this code with an older `Beam` version `2.37.0`, and I had the same issue than you
- I then tested the same code with the current `Beam` last version `2.47.0` and it worked correctly

Please use the same import and upgrade your `Beam` version to `2.47.0`.

Comment: HI @Mazlum Tosun, I have updated my question with the schema I am using. Can u check for that schema, if your code is working.?

Comment: Hi @Amarjeet, I just tested with your schema and it works correctly.

Comment: Hi @Mazlum Tosun, its still failing. Which import statement u are using?

Comment: I added all the imports in my answer. Which `Apache Beam` version are you using ?

Comment: Hi @Mazlum Tosun, its 2.47.0. I have also changed my import to 'from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import parse_table_schema_from_json'. I am runnning this on colab notebook, is that causing problem?

Comment: You have to be sure, you are using the `2.47.0` version. You can also test it in a local project in a virtual env (with `Apache Beam` 2.47.0) to confirm my answer and proposition.

Comment: I ran that code on cloudshell,and it worked.But,the schema which its generating is not recognised by beam. Can u check this question.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76324300/how-to-write-nested-json-data-to-bigquery-using-apche-beam