# How to write nested json data to bigquery using apche beam?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Hi I have a file containing multilevel nested JSON data.
I want to load that data to Bigquery using apache beam.
Below are content of the file:

```
{"id":1,"name":"A","status":"ACTIVE","dataProvider":{"name":"Exelate 3PD"},"endDateTime":{"date":{"year":2038,"month":1,"day":19},"hour":14,"minute":14,"second":7,"timeZoneId":"Australia/Sydney"}}
{"id":2,"name":"B","status":"ACTIVE","dataProvider":{"name":"Exelate 3PD"},"endDateTime":{"date":{"year":2038,"month":1,"day":19},"hour":14,"minute":14,"second":7,"timeZoneId":"Australia/Sydney"}}
{"id":3,"name":"C","status":"ACTIVE","dataProvider":{"name":"Exelate 3PD"},"endDateTime":{"date":{"year":2038,"day":19},"hour":14,"minute":14,"second":7}}
```

Below is my schema of BQ table:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "id",
      "type": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "status",
      "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
      "fields": [
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "name",
          "type": "STRING"
        }
      ],
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "dataProvider",
      "type": "RECORD"
    },
    {
      "fields": [
        {
          "fields": [
            {
              "mode": "NULLABLE",
              "name": "year",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "mode": "NULLABLE",
              "name": "month",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            },
            {
              "mode": "NULLABLE",
              "name": "day",
              "type": "INTEGER"
            }
          ],
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "date",
          "type": "RECORD"
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "hour",
          "type": "INTEGER"
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "minute",
          "type": "INTEGER"
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "second",
          "type": "INTEGER"
        },
        {
          "mode": "NULLABLE",
          "name": "timeZoneId",
          "type": "STRING"
        }
      ],
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "endDateTime",
      "type": "RECORD"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is my code to write data to BQ

```
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import parse_table_schema_from_json
import json

import apache_beam as beam
import re

schema_data = json.dumps(json.load(open("schema.json")))
table_schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(schema_data)



def parse_json(element):
    row = json.loads(element)
    return row


inputs_pattern = 'data/orderrecords.txt'



with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
     out= (
      pipeline
      | 'Take in Dataset' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(inputs_pattern)
      | beam.Map(parse_json) 
      | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        'apt-ent-45:test.order' ,
        schema=table_schema,
        # write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
         method="STREAMING_INSERTS")

    )
```

But I am getting this error.

```
WARNING:apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery:There were errors inserting to BigQuery. Will retry. Errors were [{'index': 0, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'name', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': 'no such field: name.'}]}, {'index': 1, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'name', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': 'no such field: name.'}]}, {'index': 2, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'name', 'debugInfo': '', 'message': 'no such field: name.'}]}]
```

Does anyone know ,whats the issue,or any other way to write nested data to BQ using apache beam.

Comment: your schema is incorrect. In particular, you define `name` (your 3rd field from top) as a nested record which it is not. Make it to a normal field and it should work - if there are no other bugs in your schema.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the nested fields, it is in the schema.
In your data, there are two fields called name

```
{"id":1,"name":"A","status":"ACTIVE","dataProvider":{"name":"Exelate 3PD"},...}
```

While your schema defining only one field:

```
,
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "name",
      "type": "STRING"
    }
  ],
  "mode": "NULLABLE",
  "name": "dataProvider",
  "type": "RECORD"
},
```

So, you need to add the name filed to your schema:

```
{
 "fields": [
 {
  "name": "id",
  "type": "INTEGER",
  "mode": "NULLABLE"
},
{
  "name": "name",
  "type": "STRING",
  "mode": "NULLABLE"
},
{
  "name": "status",
  "type": "STRING",
  "mode": "NULLABLE"
},
{
  "name": "dataProvider",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "STRING"
    }
  ],
  "mode": "NULLABLE"
},
...]}
```

You can use this helpful website to get or validate the BigQuery schema of your JSON objects.
https://bigquery-json-schema-generator.com/